# Facing issue while trying to check the Incoming request in Fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, fiddler

I am trying to check the incomming request to my server. Another server which has hosted MVC application. An action method is sending some data to my server. I am using Fiddler. But somehow it is not showing the incoming request.

Below mentioned are my settings in Fiddler Custom Rules..

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
        if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "IP Address:8888") 
            oSession.host = "IP Address:82";
}
```

Below mentioned are my Fiddler Options.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: A few questions: 1) Where is Fiddler located? on the server that is receiving the request? or on the client that is sending the request?  2) Is the request a HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use Fiddler as a reverse proxy. You should read the steps at http://www.fiddler2.com/r/?reverseproxy. The biggest thing to understand is that when running as a reverse proxy, you only see traffic in Fiddler if the client's URL is changed to point at Fiddler.

Comment: I don't have domain. I am operating with IP address. That's the reason I mentioned IP address in my query. Option #2 mentioned in the article as provided you you is already mentioned in my query. So Option #2 does not works. Option #1 I have checked, it's not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ssl connection then you need to enable option 'capture https connection' from 'https' tab. Did you try to invoke request from other browser like chrome ? Does fiddler capture anything?

You don't need custom rule for this case. It should work if you enable these settings. I have faced only some problems in other browsers like FF.

Comment: When you invoke request from chrome/IE it still doesn't work? Does fiddler log any other requests? from google for example. What version of fiddler and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can answer your question fully without knowing a few additional pieces of information.

If the request being made is not a HTTP request, Fiddler will not be able to handle it.
Also, if you're using the loopback address *localhost* then Fiddler may not be able to find it.